# Flutter Internal Error - Android Emulator

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm unable to find the error code that's occurring due to some internal error. {I'm using VS code}

This is the error that I get:

```
I/FirebaseAuth(26473): Logging in as xyz@xyz.xyzw with empty reCAPTCHA token
D/EGL_emulation(26473): app_time_stats: avg=196.98ms min=3.58ms max=487.15ms count=5
W/System  (26473): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/TrafficStats(26473): tagSocket(141) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
E/RecaptchaCallWrapper(26473): Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)with exception - An internal error has occurred. [ INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS ]
I/flutter (26473): INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS
```

This is the code:

```
try {
     final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                email: email, password: password);
     print(userCredential);
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
     print(e.code);
}
```

The `e.code` part never gets printed out due to this internal error. I am unable to find what is wrong with my Android Pixel 3 (Android 13) emulator.

I tried to print a "User-not found" statement but that also doesn't work. This all does not work even when I catch all the exceptions and not just the specific `FirebaseAuthException`.

Comment: What is "this internal error" you refer to?  Are you sure that catch block is not the thing printing "INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS" on the last line?

Comment: Uh.... I just checked again. I guess the error I was looking to find was INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS. But the internal error still shows up and it technically shouldn't. Why is that? I am unable to find the reason behind that